# How to interpret lens distortion coefficients in iOS Portrait mode EXIF data

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, camera-calibration, ios-camera

iOS provides lens distortion information for images obtained with the iPhone depth cameras, specifically the front-facing TrueDepth camera and the rear-facing Portrait mode camera. These lens distortion coefficients are stored in the [`AVCameraCalibrationData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcameracalibrationdata) class's [`lensDistortionLookupTable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcameracalibrationdata/2881129-lensdistortionlookuptable) instance. This lookup table has 42 values and the interpretation of this lookup table is explained clearly Apple's documentation and in `AVCameraCalibrationData.h`.

I have observed that there is also a set of 8 coefficients in the `Lens Distortion Coefficients` EXIF field in the captured HEIC file. I haven't found any documentation of these coefficients and haven't been able to make sense of them. I tried assuming that they are polynomial coefficients (as described [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/lens/)) or using them as coefficients in [OpenCV's camera calibration model](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html), to no avail. Can anyone shed light on how to use these coefficients?

I've plotted the two sets of values below.[image: Plot comparing AVCameraCalibrationData lookup table values to EXIF Lens Distortion Coefficients]

EDIT: A tantalizing hint in an [old Apple Developer Forum post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/272366), but not enough to get the answer.

> The lens distortion coefficients stored in HEIF files are not the same as the lensDistortionLookupTable. They are a more compact way of storing the data needed to generate the lookup table.

Comment: Where does Apple explain how to use these 42 parameters?  (I just want to correct barrel distortion from a 2D image.)